# Delete all ListView rows

Tags: android, android-listview

I have successfully integrated a pulltorefresh listview to my actual code.

However, when the list get updated it adds all the rows that exist to the end of the list. I come to the idea to clear all the list element before making the updates but i am stick on

**how to remove these rows inside the listview. The row item are cacheable element i think something like clear cache can work ?** Any idea please. I want to get rid of the listview rows.

```
<com.dmobile.pulltorefresh.PullRefreshContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    />
```

Here's my efficient adapter

```
            EfficientAdapter efficienadapter=new EfficientAdapter(Actualites.this,result);
            //EfficientAdapter.isActusAstuce=true;
            mList.setAdapter(efficienadapter);
```

this is my oncreate method

mRefreshHeader = new TextView(this);

```
        mImage= new ImageView(this);

        mRefreshHeader.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);

        mRefreshHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        mRefreshHeader.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

        mRefreshHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
```

LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

```
        mRefreshHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        mRefreshHeader.setText("Pull to refresh...");


        mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

      //  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
           //     ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

       // params.leftMargin=50;

       // mImage.setLayoutParams(params);

        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("boutton_retour", "drawable", getPackageName());

        //mImage.setImageResource(id);   

        mContainerView = (PullRefreshContainerView) findViewById(R.id.container);

        mContainerView.setRefreshHeader(mRefreshHeader);

        mContainerView.setRefreshHeader(mImage);

        mContainerView.setOnChangeStateListener(new OnChangeStateListener() {

            @Override

            public void onChangeState(PullRefreshContainerView container, int
```

state) {
                    switch(state) {

```
                case PullRefreshContainerView.STATE_IDLE:

                case PullRefreshContainerView.STATE_PULL:

                    mRefreshHeader.setText("Tirez pour actualiser...");

                    break;

                case PullRefreshContainerView.STATE_RELEASE:

                    mRefreshHeader.setText("Relâchez pour rafraîchir...");

                    break;

                case PullRefreshContainerView.STATE_LOADING:

                    mRefreshHeader.setText("Chargement en cours...");

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override

                        public void run() {
                            Actualites.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override

                                public void run() {

                                    try {

                                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                                    } catch
```

(InterruptedException e) {

```
        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    //refresh ui

                                    new loadingTask().execute("");


                                    mContainerView.completeRefresh();
                                }
                            });

                        }


                    }).start();

                    break;

                }

            }

        });


        mList = mContainerView.getList();

        mList.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // PostList for ListView

        /// START AsyncTask here

        new loadingTask().execute("");


  note       new loadingTask().execute("") is an async background task
```

Comment: If you have access to the adapter and it is an `ArrayAdapter`, you can do `adapter.clear();` followed by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. You should still post your code though, it's hard to say exactly how to clear something if we don't know your implementation.

Comment: i am using an efficient adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, clear the result array/ arrayList or list, ...
after that, notify the adapter to sync list item

```
result.clear();
efficienadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope this help

Comment: what is .notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any view reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: but if i put result.clear() in my onpostexecute it will clear all data and listview will be null

Comment: i still don't get it, need a break talk to you later